# Java: URL.openStream() - use IPv4

Tags: java, url, stream, ipv6, ipv4

By default `url.openStream();` uses IPv6.  My schools server silently blocks IPv6.  This causes `url.openStream();` to hang for 3 minutes and 15 seconds.  Is there a way that I can get url.openStream() to use IPv4 by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set java.net.preferIPV4Stack=true

As per : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html